# how select data with last month on postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have data with a `column` with dates, how do I output all records that have a last date `Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM`?

```
| 1 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 2 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 3 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 4 | Monday, January 28, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 5 | Monday, January 28, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 6 | Monday, January 28, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 7 | Monday, January 27, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 8 | Monday, January 27, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 9 | Monday, January 27, 2018 12:00 AM |
```

Comment: same SQL? `where column_name = 'TIMESTAMP'`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun 
`type/Date`

Comment: `date  calendar date (year, month, day)`

Comment: sorry that confused you, date in 'TIMESTAMP'

Comment: try `select max(timestamp_column) from tablename`

Comment: `where column_name = timestamp '2018-01-29 00:00:00'`?

Comment: I need all rows with last date, | 1 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 2 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 3 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM |

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
select * from table where extract(dow from date_field) = 1
```

1 is Monday
7 is Sunday

Comment: how get  `last date` ?

Comment: what do you mean by last date? The row with latest date if it is monday or the row with most recent Monday?

Comment: all rows with last date:  | 1 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM 
| 2 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM | 
| 3 | Monday, January 29, 2018 12:00 AM |